# UBUNTU 20.04 --- Grub appers but doesn't continue + Settings doesn't show when I click

Tags: grub2, desktop-icons

After installed Ubuntu 20.04, my **grub** was/is ok, but when I select the option, **my computer doesn't continue**. It stops, showing the underscore  freeze and I have to restart the pc by the buttom. My grub is dual boot and when I was with 19.10 works very well.

Plus

When I click with the right buttom of the mouse to **change the settings in the desktop, seems that I didn't click in anything**. The icons in the desktop doesn't apper too.

Do you know answer this strange things?

Thanks.